# Did I just discover a bug in CSS or am I overlooking something?

Tags: html, css

I have these styles for all my a links globally. I am not able to override the a link style in a div on the same page.

```
a, a:visited{
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Now I want to override the style for anchor link to change its color to white on hover but only in a div of multiple classes unseen and notification container like this one...

```
<div class="unseen notificationContainer">                     
    <a href="profile?customerId=1365764036258">
        <strong>robert</strong>
    </a>
    sent you a friend request 
    <a href="friend_request?type=accept&amp;notificationId=1365764054463">
        Accept
    </a>
    <a href="friend_request?type=reject&amp;notificationId=1365764054463">
        Reject
    </a>          
</div>
```

so I add the following to my CSS

```
.unseen{
    background: #09f;
    color: #fff;
}

.unseen a :hover{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

When the page loads hovering on first link makes changes its color to white but the other three take the color blue of the background. I have been on this for the past one hour and not it's just irritating. Style for notificationContainer is as below

```
.notificationContainer{
    width: 390px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider editing question title to be more specific to the actual problem

Answer (score 7):

CSS cannot possibly have bugs, only a browser can (unless you mean errors in the CSS specification, etc).

That said, this is a bug in your code and not with the browser:

```
.unseen a :hover{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The space between `a` and `:hover` means any element that is `:hover` and *within* `a`, much like `.unseen a` means `a` elements within `.unseen`, so that won't work. You need to remove that space:

```
.unseen a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply sir, I have tested it on a clean page and it works, but on the original page no. I have to check and see what other rules may be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're after - your question doesn't really make it clear. Forgive me if I've miss-guessed. Does this help? (You can target elements with multiple classes)

```
<style>
a, a:visited{
outline: 0;
cursor: pointer;
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.unseen.notificationContainer a:hover
{
    background: #09f;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.notificationContainer
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="unseen notificationContainer">                     
    <a href="profile?customerId=1365764036258"><strong>robert</strong></a>
    sent you a friend request 
    <a href="friend_request?type=accept&amp;notificationId=1365764054463">Accept</a>
    <a href="friend_request?type=reject&amp;notificationId=1365764054463">Reject</a>          
</div>
```

Comment: The class `unseen` is added dynamically to the `notificationContainer` div if the notification has not been read. What i want is for the unread notifications to have a blue background. but since the links on hover change to blue a blue background renders them invisible so i wanted them to change to white on hover.